# iptables port forwarding lo web-server

Tags: iptables

I have a local web server on 12345 port(can't change) and I want to forward port it from lo via iptables in command line.  Forwarding is allowed.

`` `iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i lo -p tcp --dport 8080 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.2.15:12:125` ``

.  No errors, but when I log in from the browser (127.0.0.1:8080) does not work.  When I go to the ip server (10.0.2.15:12345) everything works fine.  What am I doing wrong?

Sorry, if there are many mistakes in the text, it was translated from Ukrainian using Google Translate.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/182421/forwarding-a-localhostport-to-an-externalipnewport might answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

**Scenario:**

```
Web Server IP = 10.0.2.15 (eth0)
Hardcoded Listening Port = 12345/TCP
TCP Forward = from 10.0.2.15:8080 to 127.0.0.1:12345
```

Port forwarding from a standard NIC (`eth0`) to a loopback interface (`lo`) is disabled by default.
Remove the previous iptables rules and execute the following:

```
# Forward any traffic destined to TCP 8080 on eth0 to 12345 on loopback
$ sudo iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp -i eth0 --dport 8080 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:12345
# Then allow forwarding from standard NIC to loopback (assuming eth0 is the standard NIC)
$ sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.eth0.route_localnet=1
```

Comment: I fixed the error But nothing has changed.  I entered your command.  
 ``  No chain / target / match by that name. ``   What does this mean?

Comment: Please edit your original question so people can understand your current issue and assist you.

Comment: I have edited the answer and it worked 100% when I tested. Please accept if all works fine

Comment: You misunderstood me.  Web Server IP = 10.0.2.15 (usbnet0 -local) TCP Forward = from 10.0.2.15:12345 to 127.0.0.1:8080 My web-server on local ip